# How to keep my background from repeating?

Tags: html, css

I did this [page](http://web.comhem.se/nrz/) in 1998 and now that screens are wider the background repeats itself horizontally:

[image]

How can I make the camo-colored bar appear once at the very left only and preferably make the grey extend to the full screen? Do I have to treat the image or can I code it?

I found the change not trivial, now I just use

`<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="back4.gif" text="#333366" link="#CC0000" alink="#999999" vlink="996666" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0>`

And the background is a simple [file](http://web.comhem.se/nrz/back4.gif).

Can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: The easiest way by far is to split the image, create another element placed on the side that's just the camo, and apply the grey part alone to the body. If you're converting this to CSS, good on you; otherwise it's actually not doable in HTML unless you split the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the background using css, like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
 body {
  background: url(path/to/back4.gif) no-repeat;

}
</style>
```

This will fix the background and as for your other styling, read a bit about css.

Comment: Thank you. But I got a feeling this will not extend the grey, the background will end where the image ends with this technique(?)

Answer (score 1):

use `background-repeat:no-repeat` for stop repeating your background img ,
read from here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-repeat)

**edit:**
this link is good informative , check it- [link2](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I think that would not extend the grey beyond the image size. Ideally I would like the camo-bar and then the grey extending as far as the screen width.

Answer (score 1):

I would say do something like this

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
html{
    background: #777 url("http://i.imgur.com/t9EMKKM.jpg") top left repeat;
}
body{
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/sWhAr9t.jpg") top left repeat-y;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/hqZfW/

Comment: Be sure to save the images to your website files and reference them there - imgur won't necessarily keep it up forever. You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct if it is :)

Comment: Affirmative. I might need a day or two to actually put the code in place (just now I don't have this old password which the operator must snailmail me).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="background: url(http://web.comhem.se/nrz/back4.gif) no-repeat;" 
text="#333366" link="#CC0000" alink="#999999" vlink="996666" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0>
```

this should solve it.